# Numbers wont follow when shifting array to the left

Tags: c#, arrays, shift

Numbers can shift to the left => check.

Only the first number in the array follows, the rest disappears. 
Example how it is right now:

Input array: 1 2 3 4 5 6 
Input how many times to shift left: 3 
Output: 4 5 6 1 
How the Output should be: 4 5 6 1 2 3

Can someone help met with this probably simple solution which I can't find.

```cs
var str = Console.ReadLine();
int shift = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
var strArray = str.Split(' ');
var x = strArray[0];

for (var i = 0; i < strArray.Length - shift; i++)
{
    strArray[i] = strArray[i + shift];
}

strArray[strArray.Length - shift] = x;

for (var i = 0; i <= strArray.Length - shift; i++)
{
    Console.Write(strArray[i] + ' ');
}
```

Comment: I suggest you have a look at your program using the [Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) and step through it one by one - the problem should become clear quite quickly.

Comment: It's becoming 4 5 6 because of how you're writing the array. If you change the condition to `i < strArray.Length` in the last loop, you get this: `4 5 6 1 5 6`.

Comment: It's becoming 4 5 6 1 in my console? Not 4 5 6

Comment: Note that your code only deals with shifting numbers to the left, it doesn't deal with those numbers wrapping around to the other end.

Comment: @John Already massive thanks for helping me. Indeed your answer show ```4 5 6 1 5 6```. Which is almost correct, now the last 2 numbers needs to become ```2 3```.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to perform your shift, here is a simple method you can use

```
    public int[] shiftRight(int[] array, int shift)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();
        var toTake = array.Take(shift);
        var toSkip = array.Skip(shift);

        result.AddRange(toSkip);
        result.AddRange(toTake);

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for strings and the wraparound is necessary I would suggest to use `str.Substring(0,shift)`
and append it to `str.Substring(shift)` (don't try to reinvent the weel)
(some info about the substring method: [String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) )

otherwise the reason why it did not work is because you only saved the first value of the array instead of all the values you wanted to shift.

---

Do not save only the first value in the array

```cs
var x = strArray[0];
```

use

```cs
string[] x = new string[shift];
for (int i = 0; i < shift; i++)
{
    x[i] = strArray[i];
}
```

instead so you collect all the values you need to add to the end.

> EDIT: forgot the shifting

Shift the old data to the left

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length-shift; i++)
{
    strArray[i] = strArray[i+shift];
}
```

And replace

```cs
strArray[strArray.Length - shift] = x;
```

for

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++){
    int newlocation = (strArray.Length - shift)+i;
    strArray[newlocation] = x[i];
}
```

also replace the print loop for

```cs
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", strArray));
```

its easier and makes it one line instead of three lines of code.

(also the docs for the Join function [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8))

Comment: Thanks, again a step closer to my result but now my first numbers which just needs to shift to the left changed input: ```1 2 3 4 5 6 7``` and shifttimes: ```3```  Output: ```1 2 3 4 1 2 3```

Comment: @Batty sorry I forgot to add the shift to the left in the code.
I added the code to shift the data to the left

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick fix for you. please check following code.

I shift element to left by 1 position you can change code as par your requirement.

Input array: 1 2 3 4 5 6

Input how many times to shift left: 1

Output : 2 3 4 5 6 1

```
    int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    Console.WriteLine("\nArray1: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", nums));
    var temp = nums[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = nums[i + 1];
    }
    nums[nums.Length - 1] = temp;
    Console.WriteLine("\nAfter rotating array becomes: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", nums));
```